# What is the scientific name of this parrot?

Tags: species-identification

I found this parrot at Nehru Zoological Park which is located in Hyderabad city of India.It's head to tail length is between 30cm-35cm.Can anybody tell me the scientific name of this parrot?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a male plum-headed parakeet (Psittacula cyanocephala)

wiki: [the plum-headed parakeet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plum-headed_parakeet)